# How to convert facebook graph JSON output?

Tags: php, json, facebook-graph-api

Not sure if I'm actually doing this right but got a small piece of code from a tutorial I was watching on youtube, unfortunately the guy never posted part 2 or 3 so was left with just what he had written on the first video.

I've been trying to access all the PUBLIC posts that are available and have seen an easy way of accessing them via a link: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=i passed my exams&type=post&locale=en_GB

it presents what seems to be a massive array of information but how can I process this apparent JSON output using PHP into understandable information ? I've seen it done on a similar site thats making waves across the internet and wanted to try doing it myself.

Is this possible using the following code:

```
$fbquery = "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=i hate my boss&type=post";
$fb = file_get_contents($fbquery, 'rb');
$fbarray = json_decode($fb, true);
echo $fbarray['message'];
```

or am I going wrong with that somewhere? please bare in mind that its public information available and using the link in any address bar will produce and output without having the user login or using an access token.

Thanks for any help and its appreciated!

Dave.

Comment: Please use var_dump/print_r whenever you are not sure about the data structure contained within a variable or object. If this still does not help you understand how to access the individual pieces of data, then please go through some PHP beginners tutorials first.

Answer (score 0):

After json_decode you get an object.

If you do $fbarray->data you will get an array of objects.
Loop each object and check for its type.

Like

```
for(key in $fbarray->data){
  $element = $fbarray->data[key]; // you get each element.
  if($element->type =="photo") // check for different types
  {
     // display as photo.
    echo '<img src="$element->picture">';
  }
  if($element->type =="status") 
  {
     // display message.
    echo $element->message;
  }
}
```

You can use an online json editor like [jsonedtor](http://jsoneditor.appspot.com/) to get a tree view. This helps to understand tree structure of the json.

Comment: Hi, yeah that is great except still not sure what to do after that because the information displayed is set out as you said like a tree so say i wanted to echo out the id or message from the post, how would I get it from the $element ?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of problems here. 1) You should to urlencode your search string. Second, `$fbarray` is an object. You won't get just one item. Try this code:

```
$str = "i hate my boss";
$str = urlencode($str);
$fbquery = "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q={$str}&type=post";
$fb = file_get_contents($fbquery, 'rb');
$fbarray = json_decode($fb, true);
foreach ($fbarray as $item) { 
   echo $item['message'];
}
```

To test a public query like this, you can paste your `$fbquery` url into the address bar of a browser and see if you get data returned.

Comment: Thats brilliant and worked to a certain extent, however if you look at it when entering into an address bar and pressing enter, its split off into several parts and i tried using the $fbarray->data but that didn't work so then i tried $fbarray['data'] which gets some of the information but there are still parts that are seperate arrays, any idea how i would then go on to those?

Comment: AS @CBroe recommended, you could use `print_r($fbarray)` to see the full representation of the returned data. That will show you how to get at that variable in PHP. As a for instance, you could change the `echo` statement above to: `printf('%s said %s', $item['from']['name'], $item['message']);`